# Should I have one useDispatch per component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am transitioning a react with redux project from class components to hooks.

To dispatch actions I am importing { useDispatch } from react-redux.

Then, in each functional component, I have

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

And then

```
dispatch(someAction())
```

Is this the correct way to proceed or should the  `const dispatch = useDispatch()` be abstracted to a separate file and reused all throughout?

Thank you

Comment: @BrianThompson Even though someone might argue that it's opinion-based, I'd add that as an answer.

Comment: From the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) - _"**Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, do it like you have it. Putting it in its own file won't add any value, it'd just be a custom hook that wraps another hook.

The `react-redux` hooks rely on context, so you'd still have to call the custom hook within each component or it won't have access to the context it needs. You wouldn't be able to just export `dispatch` and call it like `dispatch(someAction())` after importing it.

You can check out the implementation of [`useDispatch` here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useDispatch.js). You'll notice it eventually uses [`useReduxContext`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useReduxContext.js) which is just a wrapper for `useContext(ReactReduxContext)`. Which means the functional component that uses `useDispatch` must be a child of `Provider` which sets that context.

So calling `useDispatch` in an abstracted function would not work. And in order to get it to work, you would lose the value of abstracting it in the first place.