# Why should I call useDispatch for each React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Yeah, this question seems like it's duplicate of this one:

[Should I have one useDispatch per component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957196/should-i-have-one-usedispatch-per-component)

But it's not duplicate. I am providing different approach:

Let's say I have 3 child-components and all of them use Redux Toolkit's dispatch function.

The usual way would be something like this:

```js
const ChildA = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(increment());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <button onClick={incr}>ChildA</button>;
};

const ChildB = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(increment());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <button onClick={incr}>ChildB</button>;
};

const ChildC = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(increment());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <button onClick={incr}>ChildC</button>;
};

export const MyApp = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const count = useAppSelector((state) => state.counter.value);

  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(increment());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={incr}>MyApp</button>

      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />

      <div>{count}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But what if I do it this way? Please see:

```js
export const glo: {
  dispatch: ReturnType<typeof useAppDispatch>;
} = {
  // @ts-ignore
  dispatch: null
};

const ChildA = () => {
  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    glo.dispatch(increment());
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={incr}>ChildA</button>;
};

const ChildB = () => {
  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    glo.dispatch(increment());
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={incr}>ChildB</button>;
};

const ChildC = () => {
  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    glo.dispatch(increment());
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={incr}>ChildC</button>;
};

export const MyApp = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  glo.dispatch = dispatch;
  if (!glo.dispatch) {
    throw new Error("dispatch is falsy");
  }

  const count = useAppSelector((state) => state.counter.value);

  const incr = useCallback(() => {
    glo.dispatch(increment());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={incr}>MyApp</button>

      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />

      <div>{count}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It also works fine as I tested it. Please tell me, why should I do it the usual way? Right now the new code (glo-based code) is larger, but that's because we have only 3 child-components. When we have 30+ child-components, the glo-based code will be much smaller and also much easier to understand.

Here is the diff:
https://i.ibb.co/tKWv2Qc/image.png

Here is the CodeSandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-monad-c99q3k?file=/src/features/index.tsx

Comment: What is the point? You're saving a line of code (meh) and tightly couple your components (bad).

Comment: A line of code in 100 components equals 100 lines of code, right? Tightly couple? I don't get it. We know for sure that dispatch function will never change, so why should we grab it with a hook? It's not intuitive, because calling a hook basicaly means that the returned value may be changed in the future, right? But we know for sure that the dispatch function will never change, it always will be the same reference to the non-changing function.

Comment: it will change if you use your components without  MyApp. This will happen if you write unit tests, for example.

Answer (score 1):

That dispatch function will, for example, change in your tests.

If you don't have tests, it's not "wrong" per se to do this in certain environments, but it's also not a big win.
If you have that one line of `const dispatch = useAppDispatch();` repeating a lot in your application, there's a good chance that, when the js bundle is transported gzipped (which is normal nowadays), it will gzip down to 3 or 4 bytes anyways.

If you really want to get rid of code here, remove the `useCallback` instead, because that's completely unnecessary when passing callbacks directly into html.